# How can I make a gif that disappears after it is finished in html?

Tags: javascript, css, html, gif

I can't have the button just become transparent because there will be buttons under the gif.

Comment: Either remove it from the DOM entirely or use `display: none` with CSS.

Comment: Do you mean you want a gif to disappear after it has played through once? Or just remove after pressing a button?

Comment: disappear after it has played once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("idofgif").style.display = "none";
```

jQuery:

```
$("#idofgif").hide();
```